# removing spare from array using hpacucli

Tags: linux, rhel, array

Whilst configuring a new array I have somehow accidentally added the same disk to 2 arrays:

```
=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array P400 in Slot 1                (sn: PAFGK0P9SX036K)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)

  logicaldrive 1 (68.3 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 72 GB, OK, spare)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 72 GB, OK, spare)



 array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)


  logicaldrive 2 (68.3 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 72 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:6 (port 1I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 72 GB, OK, spare)
```

As you can see, PV 1I:1:6 is in both Array A and B.

I want to remove PV 1I:1:6 from Array A, I have tried:

- ctrl slot=1 array A delete spares=1I:1:6
- ctrl slot=1 array A delete pv=1I:1:6

Neither of them work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the command is REMOVE not delete

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: AFAIU what they meant was `hpacucli ctrl slot=1 array A remove spares=1I:1:6`.